# Don't bind specific property to model in ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have action that creates new E-Mail in database. Code is like:

```
[ValidateModel]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(string username, [FromBody] EmailDTO email)
    ...
    this.repository.Add(username, email)
```

But API user can set 'Id' property and it causes to conflicts in database.
Can I ignore 'Id' property when binding without creating custom model binder or changing constructor of DTO? Like Bind(Exclude='...') but in WebApi?

What are known ways to prevent mass assignment in controllers' actions?

Answer (score -2):

We can control the deserialization with the below attributes.
This attributes excludes the property to the process of serialization and deserailization.

```
[XmlIgnore]
[JsonIgnore]
public int ID { get; set; }
```